# How to get name of called method (added dynamically) in Python?

Tags: python, oop, methods

I have class:

```
class SimpleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def init_levels(self):
        levels = get_levels_list()
        for level in levels:
            Transplant(foo, Simplelog, method_name=level)
```

Transplant is a class for dynamically adding methods to class:

```
class Transplant:
    def __init__(self, method, host, method_name=None):
        self.host = host
        self.method = method
        self.method_name = method_name
        setattr(host, method_name or method.__name__, self)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        nargs = [self.host]
        nargs.extend(args)
        return apply(self.method, nargs, kwargs)
```

Foo is a function for "transplanting":

```
def foo(self):
    return
```

How can I get called method name inside foo?

For example I execute:

```
simpleinst = SimpleClass()
simpleinst.init_levels()
```

How can I modify my code for getting called method name in foo definition body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pass it in explicitly:

```
class Transplant:
    def __init__(self, method, host, method_name=None):
        self.host = host
        self.method = method
        self.method_name = method_name or method.__name__
        setattr(host, method_name or method.__name__, self)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        nargs = [self.host, self.method_name]
        nargs.extend(args)
        return apply(self.method, nargs, kwargs)
```

and extend `foo` to accept that as an argument.

Comment: Thank! I just replace nargs = [self.host] to nargs = [self] and now I have all method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [`getattr`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm)?

```
getattr(self, "method")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a function factory, `make_foo`:

The key step is redefining the function's `func_name` attribute:

```
foo.func_name = name
```

---

```
class SimpleClass:
    def init_levels(self):
        levels = ['foo', 'bar']
        for level in levels:
            # Your original code defined this on `SimpleLog`. Did you mean `SimpleClass`?
            setattr(SimpleClass, level, make_foo(level))

def make_foo(name):
    def foo(self):
        print('{n} has been called'.format(n = foo.func_name))

    foo.func_name = name
    return foo

simpleinst = SimpleClass()
simpleinst.init_levels()
simpleinst.foo()
# foo has been called
simpleinst.bar()
# bar has been called
```